# Beamer: uncover frame number based on variable/counter

Tags: beamer, counters, calculations

Current Situation:

```
\begin{frame}

% Part one of frame (including several \pause commands)
% I am working on this

% Part two (finished)

\begin{itemize}
\item<7-> Text \visible<8>{more Text}
\item<9-> Text {\color<10->{blue} more Text}
\item<11-> Text
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
```

Obviously, when I change the number of `\pause`commands in part 1 then I have to change the explicit given frame numbers for the animation in part 2.

I would like to have a solution where I only had to change one line but the relative relations in part two stay unchanged. I tried this (without success):

```
\newcounter{xx}
\begin{frame}

% Part one (including several \pause commands)

% Part two (finished)
% Note that parallel animations occur


\begin{itemize}
\item<7-> Text {\color<8-9>{blue} more Text}
\item<7-> Text \visible<8->{more Text} \visible<9->{more Text}
\item<10-> Text
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
```

Is there similar or even simpler solution?

**Edit:** add parallel animations (which IMHO inhibit the use of `\item<+->`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use relative overlays instead of absolute numbers. Some of your effects require an offset (`(1)`) in addition.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

% Part one of frame (including several \pause commands)
% I am working on this

% Part two (finished)

\pause[6]

outside text

\begin{itemize}
\item<+(1)-> Text \visible<+(1)>{more Text}
\item<+(1)-> Text {\color<+(1)>{blue} more Text}
\item<+(1)-> Text
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

Or for your updated example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\pause[6]

outside text

\begin{itemize}
\item<+(1)-> Text {\color<+(1)-+(2)>{blue} more Text} 
\item<+(-1)-> Text \visible<.->{more Text 8} \visible<+->{more Text 9}
\item<+-> Text
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thx for the `\pause[6]` trick. However for the main question: I think I need to specify the frames "explicitly but variable" due to parallel occurring animations (see edit)

Comment: @basweber see my update. It does not matter in which direction the offset goes.

Comment: OK. It works like I want but I dont fully understand. Do you have a doc link at hand?

Comment: @basweber http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf, section `9.6.4 Incremental Specifications`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `<+->` which means something from next until end of frame. If you
comment out one of the items in Part 1 everything in Part 2 should work out.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}{}%>>>
  % Part 1
  \begin{itemize}
    \item<+-> I don't know
    \item<+-> which parts
    \item<+-> of this
    \item<+-> I use
  \end{itemize}
  % Part 2
  \begin{itemize}
    \item<+-> this part
    \item<+-> is fixed
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}%<<<

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think I need to specify the frames "explicitly but variable" due to parallel occurring animations (see edit).